# Global value has unsetted at the first time inserting data to MySQL

Tags: php, global-variables, global

In a function, I am creating a page and then adding content to related to the page.

Page columns and content columns are located in different tables. So my codes like this:

```
public function PageAndContent(...) {
  global $lang;

  $page = $db->exe("INSERT INTO table (column1{$lang->sit},column2{$lang->sit},...) VALUES (value1,value2,...)");
  $last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id();

  $content = $db->exe("INSERT INTO content (page_id, column1{$lang->sit},column2{$lang->sit},...) VALUES ( $last_insert_id, value1,value2,...)");
}
```

While inserting data into `content` table, I am getting an error `Trying to get property of non-object...`

So I think `global $lang` value is expiring after first inserting. Maybe defining a variable after `global` and set the value to `$lang->sit` could solve the problem, but I am using some other functions in the `PageAndContent()` function (method) and the other functions also use `global $lang`. Those `$lang` globals may unset too after first inserting data, because some other functions return same error too.

Comment: Where is $lang set originally? Did you set it before calling this function? What is its value before calling this function?

Comment: So remove the SQL from the equation: does the same error still occur? If so, you have the problem. Make a *minimal* (and *complete/relevant*) test-case and make sure the title reflects the problem, not the implementation scenario.

Comment: `$lang` is a language class and an instance is taken at the top of the page. And yes, the problem causes still. Every way that I have tried, results are same.